# Ошибка парсинга при кроссдоменном AJAX запросе

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsonp

Итак, обо всем по порядку.
Пытаюсь общаться с longpoll сервером VK из javascript. Делаю AXAJ запрос типа jsonp. Возникает ошибка. Вывел ошибку: parseerror. Проблема была на поверхности: longpoll контакта банально не умеет в jsonp. P.S. данные от сервера всё же приходят (в пакетах браузера они есть). Данные в формате json, а так как отправляю jsonp, браузер ждет в ответ callback.
Так вот, вопрос следующий: есть какой-то способ вытащить эти данные ?
P.P.S. сделал пока через сервер всё это дело, но уж очень хочется организовать на клиентской стороне.

Answer (score 1):

Все просто: надо использовать тот формат, который поддерживает сервер.

Если сервер отдает данные в виде jsonp - используйте jsonp. Иначе используйте json. Никакой магии.

---

Если же вам не разрешено использовать API на клиентской стороне - то у вас ничего не получится, как бы вы не старались.

Comment: Я, вроде, не аутист. Разумеется, я сразу попробовал отправить в json, так как контакт в json работает. НО мне нужен кроссдоменный запрос. А json таковым не является. И все попытки дописать crossDomain: true и прочие параметры не увенчались успехом. Политика безопасности браузера не дает совершить такой запрос. В ответ: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource..

Comment: @Platinum обновил ответ

Comment: Дак в том-то и дело, что это стандартный метод API "для всех". Но работает он онли в JSON.

Comment: @Platinum если бы он был "для всех" - там были бы настроены нужные заголовки.

Comment: Большинство клиентов вк работают с longpoll.

Comment: Из php ведь всё нормально у меня работает

Comment: @Platinum потому что вне браузера заголовки CORS не проверяются.

Comment: Нет ли какой-нибудь хитрой манипуляции, с помощью которой можно было бы отправить запрос как jsonp, а ответ не парсить, а забрать обычной строкой ?

Comment: @Platinum конечно же нет. Это была бы очень глупая дыра в защите.